# How to print the path to the place where program was compiled in c

Tags: c, environment-variables

I know we can print the path of the current working directory using something like `getcwd()` but if the program was compiled in one place and the executable was copied to some other place, it will give the result as the new directory.

How do we store the value of `getcwd()` or something during compilation itself?

Comment: I don't think you can do exactly what you want, but you can use `__FILE__` to get the path of the file, as specified to the compiler.  If you use `gcc -c file.c` then `__FILE__` will not contain the path, but if you use `gcc -c /home/fred/file.c` then it will contain the path.  Alternatively, you could pass in *exactly* what you want from your Makefile as your own maco, then use the macro in your file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass it as a compile-time define :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("COMPILE_DIR=%s\n", COMPILE_DIR);
    return 0;
}
```

And then :

```
/dir1$ gcc -DCOMPILE_DIR=\"$(pwd)\" current.c -o current
```

Resulting in :

```
/dir1$ ./current 
COMPILE_DIR=/dir1
/dir1$ cd /dir2
/dir2$ cp /dir1/current ./
/dir2$ ./current
COMPILE_DIR=/dir1
```

Comment: Ok, all know compilers allow to declare compile time macros. But not all compilers have gcc as name...

Comment: @SergeBallesta : the gcc call was meant as an example - illustrating the proposed solution of using a compile-time define. On different platforms this can be different, but surely I can't possibly be expected to list an example for all possible combinations of OS, IDE, build tool, compiler, shell, ...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using makefiles, in makefile, add a macro that retain the `pwd`
result:

Makefile:

```
CFLAGS += -DCURRENT_DIR=\"$(shell pwd)\"
```

In c file, use this value:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("file %s compiled from %s\n", __FILE__, CURRENT_DIR);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use cmake in you build process, you can add `add_definitions(-DSOME_DIR="${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")` to a correct CMakeLists.txt file. That is equivalent to `#define SOME_DIR "binaries_dir"` in the code.

Alternatively you can use any other build automation tool to make sure compiler gets passed the correct -D (GNU) or /D (MSVC) flag to generate a correct definition (or pass it to compiler manually, which is no different from specifying it in the code).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your compiler this may work:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("This file path: %s\n", __FILE__);
}
```

`__FILE__` is a predefined string literal that contains the full path of the .c file at compilation time.

If you want just the directory, you need to can strip off the filename yourself by a some trivial string manipulations.

This works under Visual Studio 2017. I didn't test it with other platforms. Apparently on most other platforms `__FILE__` just contains the filename without the path.

Comment: `__FILE__` isn't giving full paths. Its only giving a path relative to where I compiled the program. The relative path is also wrong when I move the executable

Comment: @UditSanghi yes, apparently this is platform dependent.